# My flexbox divs all align in a column. I need them to align one in a column and then in the other row in two divs

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to do a flexbox with a vertical navigation on the left that has 100% height and beside that a header with 30% height and a content space taking the other 70% of the height. I'm just learning how to code sorry.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav>
  </nav>
  <div id="column2">
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 100em;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50em;
  width:20em;
}

#column2 {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 50em;
  flex-basis: 100em;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
  height: 20em;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

main {
  background-color: pink;
  flex: 1;
  height: 30em;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Fiddle for the code in question: https://jsfiddle.net/shbf4bx1/

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

nav {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 70%;
  flex-flow: column;
}

header{
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}

main {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 0 0 70%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav>
  </nav>
  <div id="content">
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```